Build one-file script.js with SvelteKit packaging?
I've built packages using SvelteKit (docs) that I can use in other projects. The build folder typically consists of an index.js that exports a ComponentName.svelte. Then, in another project, I would import it by doing import { ComponentName } from "component-name".
Now I have a use case where I would prefer to import a package using eg. <script src="/path/to/component-name/script.js" />.
Is it possible to use SvelteKit's packaging whereby it builds a single script.js file, instead of a build folder with multiple .js and .svelte files?

For a single file you also need to disable chunks, see e.g. this answer. A comment also suggests setting a function as shown here, possibly required in newer Vite/Rollup versions.
